# SqlAlchemy python script hangs while executing SQL Server Stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am working on a Python script that makes use of SqlAlchemy library to execute Stored Procedure on SQL Server. I am passing XML contents to the stored procedure.

```
xml_text = "<root><element>some xml contents</element></root>"
query = PROCS['myStoreProc']
session = get_session()
result = session.execute(text(query, bindparams=[bindparam('xmlContent', value=xml_text)])).fetchall()
session.commit()
return result
```

I am able to get the query and session fine. But for some reason the command session.execute hangs. It neither returns any result nor any exception.